# Briefest way to display TimeSpan value as an elapsed time e.g. 1:45:33

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, timespan

I'd like an easy way to display any TimeSpan as an elapsed time without using loops or custom logic
 e.g.

```
hours : minutes : seconds
```

I'm sure there must be a .NET built-in or format string that applies, however I'm unable to locate it.

Comment: I found this but I am pretty sure it's specific to .NET 4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question itself isn't a duplicate but the answer, I assume, is what you are looking for - [Custom format Timespan with String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058637/custome-format-timespan-with-string-format). To simplify your solution further you could wrap that functionality up in an extension method of Timespan.

Comment: No extension methods in .NET 2.0

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with `TimeSpan.ToString()`?

EDIT: You can use a DateTime as an intermediate formatting store:

```
TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan(1, 45, 33);
string s = string.Format("{0:H:mm:ss}", new DateTime(a.Ticks));
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Not pretty but works.

Comment: Wouldn't ToString display milliseconds aswell?

Comment: Because I'm often getting fractions of seconds like  `1:45:33.5060000`

Comment: You will if your TimeSpan contains fractions of seconds, yes. I am editing my answer with a workaround.

Comment: The edited version displays `12:00:43` instead of `00:00:43`.

Comment: @jdk: fixed that by using "H" rather than "h" in format string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(999);
string s = t.ToString("c");  // s = "00:16:39"
```

For custom formats, see this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).

Comment: OK, and you did tag it as V2. Still a useful answer so I won't delete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I use for custom formatting:

```
TimeSpan Elapsed = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5025);
string Formatted = String.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
    Math.Floor(Elapsed.TotalHours), Elapsed.Minutes, Elapsed.Seconds);
// result: "1:23:45"
```

I don't know if that qualifies as "without custom logic," but it is .NET 3.5 compatible and doesn't involve a loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Use This:** `.ToString()`

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx), the **default format** this displays is `[-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]`. This is the quickest and easiest way to display TimeSpan value as an elapsed time e.g. 1:45:33

If you have *days*, *fractions of a second*, or a *negative* value, use a **custom format** string as described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx). This would look like `.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")`

**Example:**

```
TimeSpan elapsed = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 45, 33);
Console.WriteLine(elapsed.ToString());             //outputs: "1:45:33"
Console.WriteLine(elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));//outputs: "1:45:33"
```